# Convert some points to one polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a shapefile that contains several points with ID numbers (Point3 field) and I want to convert these points to one polygon. Some points are selected by Farm_ID field and there are 700 polygons in that field.

For example, Point3 field, I want 1 to 190 points to be one polygon. Because that points has same name 'SCAPD01-1' in Farm_ID field

If I select points based on value in Farm_ID field one by one. It is not effective.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to 1 to 190 points to be one polygon

Answer (score 0):

See:

[How To: Convert a point feature class to a polygon feature class](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012380)

For example:

- Points to Line then Feature To Polygon

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model to convert your selected points to a single polygon.

And for that, you need to implement three of the ArcGIS Desktop tools :

1. "Select", so you can select your desired points (1 to 190 in your case) with an SQL expression
2. "Points To Line", to convert the selected points to a line layer
3. "Feature To Polygon", to convert the line to a polygon

[image]

For example, with two parameters, you should get something like this after running the model :

[image]